# Form NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have a problem with NSPredicate. Can't think of a way of how to write it and can't find nothing similar.
I have this predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"followedBy.username like %@", username];
```

And this returns all users that follows given user. I want to expand this predicate that it would also return user with ids' in the NSSet.

UserIDSetExample = @"1, 15, 14, 17, ..."

So in the end I would like that this predicate returned following user plus users with ids' from the set.

Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated!!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is "followedBy" a property of your User object? What type is it?

Comment: @MarcinKuptel it is a property, it is an NSSet of Users

Comment: So your predicate returns all the followers whose name matches whatever is in "username"?

Comment: @MarcinKuptel i have an entity called master which has a property username. The predicate returns all user which are following a user with this given username

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your predicate should look like this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"followedBy.id in %@ OR followedBy.username like %@", idsSet, username];
```

Matching by ID should be first condition in the `OR` because searching if the ID (number) is in the set will likely be faster than string compares for the username

Comment: thanks! That is working!
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"identifier IN %@ OR followedBy.username like %@",self.userSet,  username];
but if user id is in the set and user is following me, than it returns two user, is there a way to ensure that this wouldn't happen?

Comment: That is weird, its not happening to me. If the user's ID is in the set, it matches -> done. If it is not, than it tries to check users by name. I don't see where this could happen. However, quick solution to remove duplicates from the array is to convert the results array (from the predicate) to `NSSet` and back again like this: `NSArray *uniqueArray = [[NSSet setWithArray:array] allObjects];`

Comment: i thought about this solution, but if the predicate returns sorted array, converting to nsset and back to nsarray would lose sorting or not?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I haven't thought about sorting. NSSet does not keep order. But I still don't see why you are getting duplicates in the results. Only reason could be duplicate data in your source filtered array. Btw: `[array valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects"]` can get uniques from the array, but only concrete properties like `NSString`, not all the objects.

Comment: I am a bit lost with these predicates, but it seems if the id is in the set, and the user follows me, then it is returned two times. distinctUnionOfObjects is kind of a solution, but i would like to understand this and use it right.

Comment: it seems using only this [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"identifier IN %@], returns couple of the same objects, i guess there is an error elsewhere in my code :/

Comment: As I said before. I suppose there are some duplicates in your data you are filtering using the predicate. You will probably have to manually filter the array for duplicates after filtering using predicate. Its no big deal ;-)

Comment: yep theres duplicates, so thanks for the help, but you where right about the predicate, so your answer is right! Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

It can be array, set, or dictionary (as pointed out by @MikePollard) and you can use the following pattern for your predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id IN %@", idArray]
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, is this possible only with an array?
if I would write it like this:
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id IN %@", idSet],
it wouldn't work?

Comment: The collection may be an array, a set, or a dictionary—in the case of a dictionary, its values are used.